# how to add user authentification to node red from a webpage that run on the same server

Tags: nginx, web, node-red

I have problem with node-red.
I have a server and i have node-red running on it, i know how to create user authentification by editing setting.js file but what i want to do is that i want to be able to create other users from a webpage that is running on the same server.
I can run a python script that edit the setting.js file and i can edit it mannualy,
but i want to be able to create and remove users from the webpage that is running on the same server.
i am using ubuntu and ngninx on my server.

Answer (score 0):

The Node-RED security documentation includes a section on adding custom user authentication [here](https://nodered.org/docs/user-guide/runtime/securing-node-red#custom-user-authentication). It explains how you can replace the hard coded user information with a module that will authenticate a given user. Editing the `settings.js` is probably not the right approach, especially as it will require you to restart Node-RED after each change.

With this approach you can build your own back end to store and manage users. There are a couple of examples of such code available, including this [one](https://www.hardill.me.uk/wordpress/2020/10/08/node-red-authentication-plugin/) that I have written that uses MongoDB to hold the user information. The management app that creates users can be found [here](https://www.hardill.me.uk/wordpress/2020/10/19/managing-multi-tenant-node-red-instances/), but you can write your own in Python if you want.

Just as a reminder, Node-RED is not a true multi-user environment, even if you declare a number of users, they will all only have shared access to one instance and set of flows. If you want a truly multi-tenant (each user has their own instance and flows) deployment you should probably look at the entire series of posts in that collection that explains how to build such a system. You can start [here](https://www.hardill.me.uk/wordpress/2020/10/01/multi-tenant-node-red/).